# In Acts 4:7 what is the personal or family name of the captain of the temple guard?

Tags: jesus, history, jerusalem, second-temple-judaism

What personal/family name or designation 
(i.e. from Galilee or son of so-and-so) 
did the CAPTAIN of the TEMPLE GUARD use 
at the time of Jesus' trial?

A historical fiction book written by David K. inserts
a personal name into this account (based on research).
Is there a member in the community who will agree or disagree
with a biblical or religious record personal/family names of 
whom had Jesus in their custody at that time? 
Would it be the same people as Acts 4:7.

Luke 22:63 
(NLT), 
"The guards in charge of Jesus began mocking and beating him."

(NAS1977),
"And the men who were holding Jesus in custody were mocking Him, and beating Him,"

Acts 4:1 (Bible Hub Parallel version)

Comment: @Ruminator Acts 4:1, I read a historical fiction book by David Kitz:
https://www.davidkitz.ca/bookcart/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=50 ...where a personal name was inserted.

Comment: @Ruminator the "Stray cat.." is my reference to bible designations including a personal name followed by their title AND followed by "son of..." or "from a region/city".

Comment: If there is a name associated with this person I suspect it is only possible to find the answer in Church tradition and then it is matter of how much weight you would give to tradition

Answer (score 2):

We have no information about Jesus' Roman guards such as their names or origins.  Obviously Pilate had Roman soldiers at his disposal but whether they were the same company of soldiers or a different one whom the High Priest controlled is not known.

What we do know is that whatever company of soldiers guarded Jesus' tomb (Matt 27:64, John 18:3, 12) were bribed to spread a lie to cover-up Jesus' resurrection (Matt 28:8-15) and was probably different from those attached to the Roman Praetorium.  Normally. Such a story would normally result in the death of the guards (eg, Acts 12:18, 19); so it is not clear which soldiers were responsible to whom, but this suggests that they were a different company from Pilate's Praetorian guard (but it is not certain!)

However, there are a few Roman Soldiers whose details we do know such as Centurion Cornelius (Acts 10); Centurion Julius of the Augustinian Regiment (Acts 27, 28), etc.  This is all that has been revealed and recorded.